# Orientation won't unlock

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad Air 2. I was having problems with volume until I loaded the 8.1 OS. Now I have volume but my orientation is locked. I checked, orientation is not locked in the slide-up menu and I cannot find in Settings/General where I may have it locked.

Answer (score 1):

Orientation lock was an issue with early versions of iOS 8.

Simplest fix would be to update to 8.3

Comment: Oops, 8.3 is what I installed to get volume back and now orientation is locked.

Comment: hmmm… then I'd go for the simple stuff first. Reboot, then in iTunes, sync: backup: restore. Remove any 3rd party keyboards too - they've had issues